# Angular , How to hide a table row on click of a button

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a table in which each row has a delete button. on click of the button the data gets deleted. However to verify that record is deleted, I have to refresh the page. I want to hide the current row on click of the delete button. Here is my code.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Delete</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let person of people" *ngIf="!hideRow">
        <td><button (click)="delete(person.id)" title="Delete">Delete</button></td>
        <td>person.Id</td>
        <td>person.Name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and in my component.ts On delete I change the value of hideRow

```
delete(id) {  
  this.hideTr = true;
  this.personService.delete(id).subscribe(p=> console.log(p));
}
```

hideRow is a boolean variable with default value of false. The problem is that when I click on delete, all the rows become hidden(of course). How can I refer just to the current row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based from the code you provided, I would remove this part `*ngIf="!hideRow"` and add this to your component

```
delete(id) {  
    this.personService.delete(id).subscribe(p=> {
        console.log(p);
        this.people.filter( person => person.id !== id)
        // or you can use splice by using the index
    });
}
```

Now your html is simpler and no need to use `*ngIf`

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Delete</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let person of people">
        <td><button (click)="delete(person.id)" title="Delete">Delete</button></td>
        <td>person.Id</td>
        <td>person.Name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This vill not work as you throw away the result of filter()

Answer (score 3):

Simple yet more effective :

**Template Side :**

```
<tr *ngFor="let person of people" *ngIf="!person?.hideRow">
    <td><button (click)="delete(person)" title="Delete">Delete</button></td>
    <td>person.Id</td>
    <td>person.Name</td>
</tr>
```

**Component Side :**

```
delete(person) {  
  person.hideRow = true;
  this.personService.delete(person.id).subscribe(p=> console.log(p));
}
```

---

> Without changing user's (property) interface

**Template Side :**

```
<tr *ngFor="let person of people;let i = index;">
    <td><button (click)="delete(i , person.id)" title="Delete">Delete</button></td>
    <td>person.Id</td>
    <td>person.Name</td>
</tr>
```

**Component Side :**

```
delete(index , id) {  
    this.people.splice(index, 1);
    this.personService.delete(id).subscribe(p=> console.log(p));
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant but I prefer not to add properties to my interface which are not real properties of the person type.

Comment: @Iman, no problem, but still you get one more way to do it, I have solved many issue by using this way. Its just matter of way of solving problems.

Comment: @Iman , you should use the second method I have just posted now then use the accepted answer, it will loop through the data twice once on delete , second on showing data again, by my second method it will just loop once on delete.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to delete the row then you should delete it in actual instead of hide row. No need of `*ngIf="!hideRow"`. You no need to refresh the page, this is beauty of AngularJS. Below is code to delete particular row. Pass `$index` of the row:

HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Delete</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let person of people">
        <td><button (click)="delete($index)" title="Delete">Delete</button></td>
        <td>person.Id</td>
        <td>person.Name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
// delete row
$scope.delete = function(index) {
    $scope.people.splice(index, 1);
};
```