# How to show and hide a particular table <tr> row using angular 8

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.
I am using Angular 8 with bootstrap 4.
Here is my home.component.html

```
                          <table class="table" border="0">
            <thead class="thead-light">
              <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Report Issued Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Report Name and ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Report Status</th>


              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody *ngFor="let report of patient?.listDiagnosticReport">
            <tr>
              <td>{{report.id}}

              </td>
              <td>{{report.reportIssuedDate}}</td>
              <td>
                <button (click)="onShow(report.reportId)"> 
                {{report.reportName+"("+report.reportId+")"}}
                 </button>
              </td>
              <td>{{report.reportStatus}}</td>
            </tr>



            <tr id="{{report.reportId}}"  *ngFor="let procedureRequest of report?.listOfProcedures"  [hidden]="showRow">
                <td [attr.colspan]="4">
                Specimen Collected By: {{procedureRequest.procedureName}}
                <br/>
                Specimen Collection Date: {{procedureRequest.datePerformed}}
                <br/>
                Procedure Name: {{procedureRequest.procedureName}} 
                </td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
```

Here is my home.component.ts:

```
 export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  showRow: boolean = true;


  onShow(rowId: string)
  {
    if (this.showRow === true)
    {
      this.showRow = false;

    }
    else
    {
      this.showRow = true;
    }
  }
```

I placed an id on the row and when it first load all of the rows disappear. When I click on the button it trigger the onShow method with the reportId as an argument.
How can I make the particular row show in Angualr 8?

Thank you for everyone's suggestion and help.
I am able to hide the row at the beginning and when click the button show the row.

```
         onShow(reportId: string) {
        const el = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector(`#${reportId}`);
        if (el.hidden === false) {
        el.hidden = true;
        } else {
         // el.classList.remove('hidden');
           el.hidden = false;
        }
      }
```

My problem is that I have more than one row with the same id. In fact I have 3 rows with the same Id and when I click the button it only shows 1 row and not the other 2 rows.

This is my home.component.html:

```
         <tr id="{{report.reportId}}"  *ngFor="let procedureRequest of report?.listOfProcedures"  [hidden]="showRow">
                <td [attr.colspan]="4">
                Specimen Collected By: {{procedureRequest.procedureName}}
                <br/>
                Specimen Collection Date: {{procedureRequest.datePerformed}}
                <br/>
                Procedure Name: {{procedureRequest.procedureName}} 
                </td>
         </tr>
```

Here is the web result:
   [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2, How to hide a table row on click of a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901964/angular-2-how-to-hide-a-table-row-on-click-of-a-button)

Comment: Do you want all rows with the same ID to hide or just the row you click on?

Answer (score 4):

The reason why your code isnt working is because your `showRow` variable will apply to all the `tr` elements.

Basically what is happening is

```
<tr [hidden]="true">
</tr> 
<tr [hidden]="true">
</tr> 
<tr [hidden]="true">
</tr> 
<tr [hidden]="true">
</tr> 
<tr [hidden]="true">
</tr>
```

because `showRow` is `true`, when you apply a variable to a looped element it needs to be unique

You need to do something like this

**component.html**

```html
<!-- ... -->
<tr id="{{report.reportId}}"  *ngFor="let procedureRequest of report?.listOfProcedures">
  <! ... -->
</tr>
```

**component.ts**

```js
showHide(reportId) {
  const el = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector(`#${reportId}`;
  if (el.classList.contains('hidden') {
    el.classList.remove('hidden');
  } else {
    el.classList.add('hidden');
  }
}
```

**component.css**

```css
tr {
  display: block;
  // ...
}
tr.hidden {
  display: none;
  // ...
}
```

basically what is happening is when you click an element it will apply the `hidden` class to that element and not all the `tr` elements

**OR**

If you have control of your report object you could add a hidden field

```
report: {
  reportId: 1234,
  hidden: false
}
```

and then in your `showHide` method

```js
showHide(report) {
  report.hidden = report.hidden ? false : true;
}
```

then in your component

```html
<tr id="{{report.reportId}}" [hidden]="report.hidden">
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a object with reportId and hidden

`report = {reportId: number | string, hidden: boolean}`

and then create a list of report object with based on how many reports in that list

`for example: 
reports: report[] = [{reportId: 1234, hidden: false}, {report 1235, hidden: false}]`

then you can pass this object in your onShow method.

```
onShow(reportId) { retrun !reportId.hidden; }
```

you can pass your report from html page

```
<button (click)=onShow(reportId)></button>
```

> Note: Here you maintain reports in your ts file